# Only Last item in list shows in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 5 contents which I want to display in wrapPanels when the application starts but unfortunately, it's not working as I want. When I run the application.

```
public class Company
{
    public String EventName { get; set; }
    public String Attendees { get; set; }
    public String Date { get; set; }
}
```

}

I expect all the contents to show up, but only Hiking shows

Comment: You're reassigning com again and again basically, Second 'com' will overwrite the first one

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this problem is because you are overwriting the variable called "com" with each new value.

```
com = new Company { EventName = "Code Talks" ,Attendees ="50" , Date = "25/oct./2019" };
com = new Company { EventName = "Tic Tac", Attendees = "70", Date = "55/oct./2019" };
com = new Company { EventName = "Loney Talks", Attendees = "30", Date = "5/oct./2019" };
com = new Company { EventName = "Cofee Talks", Attendees = "50", Date = "25/oct./2019" };
com = new Company { EventName = "Hiking ", Attendees = "40", Date = "75/oct./2019" };
```

Which is equivalent to trying to store several integers like this:

```
x=5;
x=4;
x=1;
```

You will want to use some kind of array and add each item to it. If you are only ever going to use those 5 items, then a fixed length array will work fine:

```
Company[] coms = new Company[5];
coms[0] = new Company { EventName = "Code Talks" ,Attendees ="50" , Date = "25/oct./2019" };
coms[1] = new Company { EventName = "Tic Tac", Attendees = "70", Date = "55/oct./2019" };
coms[2] = new Company { EventName = "Loney Talks", Attendees = "30", Date = "5/oct./2019" };
coms[3] = new Company { EventName = "Cofee Talks", Attendees = "50", Date = "25/oct./2019" };
coms[4] = new Company { EventName = "Hiking ", Attendees = "40", Date = "75/oct./2019" };
```

Comment: Please don't suggest an array to somebody naive enough to take the suggestion seriously. `ObservableCollection<Company>` is a much better idea. Also, a local variable in his Main() method doesn't get him anywhere. He needs to expose a property of that that type for something to bind to, and he would be better off with some kind of items control to display it.

Comment: Please I have a question. In my code above the image has a click event for the 5 contents added, this takes the user to a new window. so can I create an itemscontrol for the new windows? If this is possible how do I link each new window to their respective contents

Comment: Ed, Why is ```ObservableCollection<Company>``` better in this instance?